# get last added item's id created by user x or on behalf of user x

Tags: sharepoint-addin, spservices

The function

```
 var lastID = $().SPServices.SPGetLastItemId({
                        listName: 'list1'
                    });
```

from SPServices returns last id for items that was created by current user

I want to get the id of item which was created by current user OR on behalf of current user.

I need last id with 2 conditions that either created by current user OR

created by Add-in on behalf of current user

I see this on item details

Created at 7/20/2017 12:09 PM  by app name SharePoint Add-in on behalf of :user xxxx

calling `SPGetLastItemId` return 0

I think there is something wrong that the last item which current user is creating does not properly set "Author" or something!

Answer (score 0):

*I assume, you have not set unique permissions for list items. Hence all Items of the list can be accessed by current user.*

You can Query the List items, set as sorted descending by ID, and setting Rowlimit as 1.
your query be like

```
<Query><Where><Neq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Counter'>0</Value></Neq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="ID" Ascending="False" /></OrderBy></Query>
```

Complete working code using SPServices is:

```
var lastID;
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: target_List_name,     
    CAMLQuery: '<Query><Where><Neq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Counter'>0</Value></Neq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="ID" Ascending="False" /></OrderBy></Query>',
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='ID' /></ViewFields>",
    CAMLRowLimit: 1,
    completefunc: function(xData,Status){
       $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function(){
            lastID = $(this).attr("ows_ID");
        });
        }
});
```

Comment: I don't want id of item which was created by any other user, also please check updated question details.